# What is the best 2d graphic library for javascript?

Tags: javascript, 2d, graphic

I want to make simple 2d game using javaScript.
What should i know before i start?
I'm a c# programmer and I don't have much experience with js.
Is there any design patterns should i know about?

Comment: I just made my simple library based on SFML. It's a simple graphics library to draw anything you need to https://github.com/azarus/SGL.js/
It's still in progress and not final.
I am posting this here so if someone is looking for something simpler he might want to use this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [PIXI.js](http://www.pixijs.com/) as it is really easy to use, yet is really powerful.

I made this [Game](http://willystudios.rocks/rocks) with it in 48 hours for ludumdare (doesnt work in mozilla, which is a fault in my code not pixi's)